# How to sort two firebase streams Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I retrieve two streams from firebase and merge into one stream sorted by time?

I have seen various uses of Rx and StreamGroup and StreamZip however I am not sure how to sort the resultant stream.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using `Rx.combineLatest([stream1,stream2], (values) => values);` then sorted the list after combining the stream lists inside the streambuilder:

```
List list1 = snapshot.data[0];
List list2 = snapshot.data[1];
streams.addAll(list1);
streams.addAll(list2);
streams.sort(etc...)
```